# Black image instead of linear image correction

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

the problem is that the original image is displayed correctly, and the corrected one displays black, do you know what could be the reason?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
# Uploading an image
drive.mount("/content/drive")
img = cv2.imread('./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/maxresdefault.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# Calculating the minimum and maximum pixel values
r_min = np.min(img)
r_max = np.max(img)
# Linear image correction
img_corrected = (img - r_min) * 255 / (r_max - r_min)
# Converting an image to an 8-bit format
img_corrected = np.uint8(img_corrected)
img_corrected = cv2.cvtColor(img_corrected, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Displaying the original and corrected images
cv2_imshow(img)
cv2.imwrite("./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/corrected_image.jpg", img_corrected)
img_corrected = cv2.imread("./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/corrected_image.jpg")
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

an image with correction and an image with correction are presented:
[image]
[image]

Comment: you have to be aware of your value ranges. they aren't adjusted to automatically. debug your value ranges.

Comment: There are no errors related to the range of values in this code.

Comment: I didn't say "errors". and yes, that's the issue, value ranges and data types. are you willing to debug your problem? please inspect each intermediate array.

Comment: The problem is that when calculating img_corrected, the values may go beyond the range 0-255 due to the use of the float data type. To solve this problem, I can change the data type to uint16 when calculating img_corrected and then cast it to type uint8 before output. By changing this, the result remains the same black screen.

Answer (score 0):

```py
img_corrected = (img - r_min) * 255 / (r_max - r_min)
```

In this line, `img` is a uint8 image. `img-r_min` also is. So is `(img-r_min)*255` (a little bit random, since it overflows. That is literally a way to generate pseudo-random numbers: multiplying by a number that make overflow, and keep the remainder (aka %) of that number with a smaller constant. Which you do here, implicitly, since that is implicitly the same as `(img-r_min)*255 % 256`. So, not the ideal number for a pseudo-random generator, but not so far from it. But, well, it doesn't matter. The important point is, whatever the values of `(img-r_min)*255`, they are all `np.uint8` between 0 and 255).

Therefore `(img_rmin)*255/(r_max-r_min)`, since `r_max-r_min` is 244 for this image (and should be quite close to 255 with any normally visible input image), is near 0. Your `img_corrected` is made of 0 and 1.

(You can check by displaying `img_corrected*100` for example, that some pixels are indeed 1, and most 0).

Solution is: transtype `img` first to to a datatype where your computation would not overflow, and then transtype the result back to `uint8` (which you already do, but, as is, your conversion is useless, since, and that is the problem, `img_corrected` is already a uint8).

For example

```py
img_corrected = (img.astype(np.float64) - r_min) * 255 / (r_max - r_min)
```

Or, even simpler (but less readable code)

```py
img_corrected = (img - r_min) * 255.0 / (r_max - r_min)
```

Forcing the result of the multiplication to be a float, since 255.0 is a float.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works now, but the images are very similar to each other, I would say identical

Comment: Well, yes. What this code does, is just ensure that minimum value of image is mapped onto 0, and maximum value to 255, and the rest linearly between those. Since your original image has a minimum value of 9 and max of 253, mapping that to 0-255 doesn't change much to the result. Probably nothing visible unless you have a very good screen and a very good eye.

Comment: Since you didn't say what is your objective (other that figuring out why the result is black, which is now done), I can't be sure about what to do to get a more acceptable result to you. Where you expecting a higher contrast? Then you could use `np.quantile(img, 0.1)` instead of `min` and `np.quantile(img, 0.9)` instead of max (for example) to prevent only a single low value pixel and a single high value pixel to drive the value range of the image (0.1 and 0.9 are radical example, just to illustrate. It means that the 10% lower pixel are mapped to black, and 10% higher to 255-while)